# Purpose of the id in reportSet maven?

Tags: maven, changelog, maven-site-plugin, maven-profiles

I see the following configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-changelog-plugin</artifactId>
    <reportSets>
        <reportSet>
            <id>changelog</id>
            <configuration>
                <displayFileRevDetailUrl>${changelog.fileUri}</displayFileRevDetailUrl>
                <displayChangeSetDetailUrl>${changelog.revision.fileUri}
                </displayChangeSetDetailUrl>
                <headingDateFormat>MM-dd-yyyy</headingDateFormat>
                <outputEncoding>${project.reporting.outputEncoding}</outputEncoding>
                <type>range</type>
                <range>30</range>
            </configuration>
            <reports>
                <report>changelog</report>
            </reports>
        </reportSet>
        <reportSet>
            <id>activty</id>
            <configuration>
                <displayFileDetailUrl>#</displayFileDetailUrl>
                <headingDateFormat>MM-dd-yyyy</headingDateFormat>
                <outputEncoding>${project.reporting.outputEncoding}</outputEncoding>
                <type>range</type>
                <range>30</range>
            </configuration>
            <reports>
                <report>dev-activity</report>
                <report>file-activity</report>
            </reports>
        </reportSet>
    </reportSets>
</plugin>
```

**Question**: What is the pourpose of the `id` in the `reportSet`? Where I can refer to this `reportSet`? Does it means that for example in different profiles can call different report set configurations?

Answer (score 1):

From the official [Maven model](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-model/maven.html), the [`reportSet`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-model/maven.html#class_reportSet) section states for its `id` element:

> The unique id for this report set, to be used during POM inheritance and profile injection for merging of report sets.

Hence, [**inheritance**](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance) and [**profiles**](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) are indeed the main use cases for it.

---

Going through your questions:

> What is the pourpose of the id in the reportSet?

To uniquely identify a `reportSet`.

> Where I can refer to this reportSet?

From a parent POM plugin configuration or from a profile.

> Does it means that for example in different profiles can call different report 
>   set configurations?

You can indeed override or customize its configuration by pointing to the same id via a profile.